# Show the exception of function with window alert

Tags: javascript

i want to show the exception in a window alert if one or multiple fields are not filled or wrong filled in my contact form to create a new contact.

I have a function "check()" which controls all inputs. I tried it with a try, catch block but I´m not sure which error i should hand over to the catch block.

I have problems with the saveContact() method, the check() method works and it recognizes if a field is not or wrong filled. But how can i show the error in a window.alert?

Check method

```
pruefe() {
    if (this.name.trim() === "") {
        throw ("Der Name darf nicht leer sein!");
    } else if (this.email.trim() === "") {
        throw "Die E-Mail-Adresse darf nicht leer sein!";
    } else if (this.plz.trim() === "") {
        throw "Die Postleitzahl darf nicht leer sein!";
    } else if (this.ort.trim() === "") {
        throw "Der Ort darf nicht leer sein!";
    } else if (this.strasse.trim() === "") {
        throw "Die Strasse darf nicht leer sein!";
    } else {
        if (this.plz != parseInt(this.plz) || this.plz <= 0) {
            throw "Die Postleitzahl muss eine Zahl > 0 sein!";
        } else if (!this.validateEmail(this.email)) {
            throw "Die E-Mail-Adresse besitzt kein gültiges Format!";
        }
    }
```

Method which is called when clicking save button

```
function saveContact() {



var kontakt = new Kontakt();
kontakt.name = document.querySelector("#nameID").value;
kontakt.email = document.querySelector("#emailID").value;
kontakt.plz = document.querySelector("#plzID").value;
kontakt.ort = document.querySelector("#ortID").value;
kontakt.strasse = document.querySelector("#strasseID").value;





try {
    kontakt.pruefe();  
}
catch(err) {
    window.alert(ReferenceError);
}
```

Comment: should be `window.alert(err.msg);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `throw ("Der Name darf nicht leer sein!");` Use `throw new Error("Der Name darf nicht leer sein!");`

Instead of `window.alert(ReferenceError);` use `window.alert(err.message);`

Comment: Instead of `window.alert ` just `console.log(err)` object and see the output. Make sure you `throw new Error('msg')` from each throw statement.